# Does Entity Framework 4 support Batch Inserts?

Tags: entity-framework, insert, entity-framework-4

I found [this similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373826/batch-insert-update-with-entity-framework), but this is really old.
Was it implemented in the latest version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is short and simple. [Nope](http://twitter.com/julielerman/status/20882124645)