# Efficient collection Update/Insert in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework-4

I have a similar challenge to this post: [Batch insert/update with entity framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373826/batch-insert-update-with-entity-framework) from a couple years ago, I was hoping that the story may have changed since then.

In short, I am running a RESTful service, and as such I'd like a PUT to be document-oriented and take an object along with a collection of child elements in.  The child elements have a unique string that I can use for determining existence.

Unlike the referenced poster, I don't have a query requirement; all I want to do is be able to take in a collection of my child elements and perform an insert on the child table for any that aren't already there, and an insert or delete on the many-to-many table to account for the current state of the collection.  Ideally, with some efficiency.  I realize that I might end up doing this as a sproc, I just wanted to see if there's an EF-native way that works first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you must either know which items are new or you must query DB first and merge your received items with loaded items. [EF will not handle this for you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635071/update-relationships-when-saving-changes-of-ef4-poco-objects/3635326#3635326). Also be aware that there are still [no batch modifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4407348/batching-db-commands-in-entity-framework-4-0). Each insert, update or delete is executed in separate roundtrip to database.